# Is it possible to disable the "deferred TIP" optimisation when using Intel Processor Trace?

Tags: x86, cpu, intel, cpu-architecture, trace

Section 32.4.2.3 of the Intel Software Developer's Manual Volume 3 outlines the deferred TIP optimisation for processor trace:

[image]

I have a very niche use-case where I require that the chip *not* perform this optimisation. Can it be switched off?

I don't think it can, but worth a shot. I can't see any MSR controlling such a setting...

Comment: I also didn't find any useful MSR. I wonder if one could exploit `ptwrite` (which can be made to generate FUP) to force the CPU to flush the packet queue at regular intervals.

Comment: That's a neat idea! Sadly not all chips support PTWRITE though.